How can I set different default paths for different "saving" in blender?
How can I set different default paths for different "saving" in blender?
That is, the directory that is automatically opened after selecting "save" or "imput" or "output" to open the file browser, (default)
I don't want to manually select the file directory every time I save different types of files,
So I used python to create a new project setting operator similar to maya. Although I set the file path directory of some preferences, I found that this seems to have nothing to do with the default path opened after blender's "save" or "imput" or "output" opens the file browser.

default


At present, I have always saved and exported files in system :C



File， The effect I hope to achieve


File type


File


Render， The effect I hope to achieve


Render type





Render， The effect I hope to achieve


Texture type





output， The effect I hope to achieve


output type



6. my python

import bpy
import os

# Define project folder structure
project_folders = [
    "assets",
    "autosave",
    "cache",
    "clips",
    "images",
    "movies",
    "renderData",
    "scenes",
    "scripts",
    "sound",
    "sourceimages"
]

# Check and create folders
def check_and_create_folders(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    for folder in project_folders:
        folder_path = os.path.join(path, folder)
        if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
            os.makedirs(folder_path)
            print(f"Created folder: {folder_path}")
        else:
            print(f"Folder already exists: {folder_path}")

# "Set Project" functionality: Set Blender project path
def set_project_path(path):
    check_and_create_folders(path)
    
    # Set render output path
    bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.render_output_directory = os.path.join(path, "renderData")
    bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.texture_directory = os.path.join(path, "sourceimages")
    # Set default save paths
    bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.render_cache_directory = os.path.join(path, "cache")
    bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.temporary_directory = os.path.join(path, "autosave")
    bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.sound_directory = os.path.join(path, "sound")
    
    # Autosave path
    autosave_dir = os.path.join(path, "autosave")
    bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.temporary_directory = autosave_dir

    print(f"Blender project path has been set to: {path}")
    print(f"Render output path has been set to: {bpy.context.scene.render.filepath}")

# Save images to custom directory
def save_image_to_custom_directory():
    if bpy.data.images:
        for image in bpy.data.images:
            if image.filepath_raw:
                default_dir = os.path.join(bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.project_path, "images")
                image.filepath_raw = os.path.join(default_dir, os.path.basename(image.filepath_raw))
                bpy.ops.image.save_as(filepath=image.filepath_raw)

# Menu operator: Project Setup Window
class PROJECT_OT_create_window(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "project.create_window"
    bl_label = "Confirm Project Window"

    filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Path", subtype='DIR_PATH')

    def execute(self, context):
        check_and_create_folders(self.filepath)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

# Menu operator: Set Project Path Window
class PROJECT_OT_set_project(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "project.set_project"
    bl_label = "Set Project"

    filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Path", subtype='DIR_PATH')

    def execute(self, context):
        set_project_path(self.filepath)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

# Menu function: Add buttons to the File menu
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.separator()
    self.layout.operator(PROJECT_OT_create_window.bl_idname)
    self.layout.operator(PROJECT_OT_set_project.bl_idname)

# Register classes and menu
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PROJECT_OT_create_window)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PROJECT_OT_set_project)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PROJECT_OT_create_window)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PROJECT_OT_set_project)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

If there is no way to solve it, I can only add custom "save" operators for different menus, but this seems to be more troublesome? ? I'm not sure.
PS: I saw similar addons in the blender market, but I can't buy them in my area, so I made a simple add-on myself
